# pip errors during odoo 10 installation on centos 6.8

Tags: python, postgresql, centos, pip, odoo

I'm new to odoo, trying to insatll odoo 10 community edition on CentOS 6.8. I'm following their [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html). I'm stuck on

```
"pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

Getting the following error.

```
 Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5jzK4x/psycopg2
```

P.S  I have already installed " python-devel postgresql-devel"

Comment: Well, is the pg_config executable in your PATH? If you type `pg_config` in your terminal emulator, do you get any output ?

Comment: Mm, no
-bash: pg_config: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I found this.

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-odoo-10-on-centos-7-with-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy/

If you following until "Install Odoo 10". You have the method to install odoo on centos.

I'm not sure it will work but you can try it.